# Use css variable into background-image for changing color

Tags: css, svg, background-image

I want to use my CSS variable into an background image for changing the fill property of the SVG.

```css
:root{
  --primary: red;
}

input {
  background-image: url('data:image/svg+xml,<svg    fill="var(--primary)" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 8 8"><path d="M2.3 6.73L.6 4.53c-.4-1.04.46-1.4 1.1-.8l1.1 1.4 3.4-3.8c.6-.63 1.6-.27 1.2.7l-4 4.6c-.43.5-.8.4-1.1.1z"/></svg>');
  background-position: right center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<input type="text>
```

Comment: Similar thread that may help, It is impossible to modify the svg in background image, however this thread talks about serving the svg up from a custom endpoint https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13367868/modify-svg-fill-color-when-being-served-as-background-image

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/67025375/8620333

Answer (score 1):

Not as elegant maybe, but you could do something like this.

```css
:root{
  --red: url('data:image/svg+xml,<svg fill="red" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 8 8"><path d="M2.3 6.73L.6 4.53c-.4-1.04.46-1.4 1.1-.8l1.1 1.4 3.4-3.8c.6-.63 1.6-.27 1.2.7l-4 4.6c-.43.5-.8.4-1.1.1z"/></svg>');
  --blue: url('data:image/svg+xml,<svg fill="blue" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 8 8"><path d="M2.3 6.73L.6 4.53c-.4-1.04.46-1.4 1.1-.8l1.1 1.4 3.4-3.8c.6-.63 1.6-.27 1.2.7l-4 4.6c-.43.5-.8.4-1.1.1z"/></svg>');
  --primary: var(--red);
}

input {
  background-image: var(--primary);
  background-position: right center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<input type="text">
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you can't change svg `fill`/`stroke` property, if is used as `background-image`. You could do it only if `svg` is inside the HTML as a code.