# How style an inline SVG within a pseudo-element ::before & ::after?

Tags: html, css, svg, pseudo-element

I am trying to style an SVG within a pseudo-element.

```css
p::before {
  content: url("data:image/svg+xml;charset=UTF-8,<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' class='svg-check' viewBox='0 0 20 20'><path fill-rule='evenodd' d='M10 18a8 8 0 100-16 8 8 0 000 16zm3.707-9.293a1 1 0 00-1.414-1.414L9 10.586 7.707 9.293a1 1 0 00-1.414 1.414l2 2a1 1 0 001.414 0l4-4z' clip-rule='evenodd' /></svg>");
  display: inline-block;
  height: 2rem;
  width: 2rem;
}

.svg-check {
  fill: green;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>First</p>
  <p>Second</p>
</div>
```

[CodePen Sample](https://codepen.io/G_Basak/pen/ExWJPZY)

My question is :

1. Is this possible?
2. If yes, how?
3. If no, is there any other way
   to achieve same?

Comment: 1. No 2. No 3. Recreate the content for every change

Comment: @Danny'365CSI'Engelman could you please explain the 3rd point? I am very new to html, css.

Answer (score 1):

Close, assign an empty string for `content` then use a background image. See this [article](https://css-tricks.com/lodge/svg/09-svg-data-uris/)

```css
p::before {
  content: '';
  display: inline-block;
  height: 2rem;
  width: 2rem;
  margin-right: 1rem;
  vertical-align: middle;
  background: url(https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/basic-business-1/36/Checkmark_right_icon-512.svg) no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>First</p>
  <p>Second</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Can I change the color of this image with CSS? I want to change the color of the ::before element with theme.

Comment: @G_Basak added link.

Comment: @G_Basak use mask: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67027543/8620333